# Turning a data.frame into a 3-way table with multiple levels in R

Tags: r, contingency

I would like to turn on the following, manually entered table, entered as a data.frame in R, following the code [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/vignettes/TablesInR.pdf):

```
tab <- data.frame(expand.grid(
  Hair = c("Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond"),
  Eye = c("Brown", "Blue", "Hazel", "Green"),
  Sex = c("Male", "Female")),
  count = c(32,53,10,3,11,50,10,30,10,25,7,5,3,15,7,8,
            36,66,16,4,9,34,7,64,5,29,7,5,2,14,7,8) ) 

tab

    Hair   Eye    Sex count
1  Black Brown   Male    32
2  Brown Brown   Male    53
3    Red Brown   Male    10
4  Blond Brown   Male     3
...
```

into a table as in the original `HairEyeColor {datasets}` three-dimensional array:

```
HairEyeColor
, , Sex = Male

       Eye
Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
  Black    32   11    10     3
  Brown    53   50    25    15
  Red      10   10     7     7
  Blond     3   30     5     8

, , Sex = Female

       Eye
Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
  Black    36    9     5     2
  Brown    66   34    29    14
  Red      16    7     7     7
  Blond     4   64     5     8
```

I have tried `xtabs` and `ftable` without success.

Comment: `xtabs(count ~ ., data=tab)` isn't it?

Comment: @thelatemail Quite terse, but effective. Post it as an answer for some points...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each value is in a unique category, you can just do:

```
xtabs(count ~ ., data=tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your result to be a list of data.frames, sticking with the [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/) packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
tab %>%
  split(.$Sex) %>%
  purrr::map(tidyr::spread, Eye, count)
#> $Male
#>    Hair  Sex Brown Blue Hazel Green
#> 1 Black Male    32   11    10     3
#> 2 Brown Male    53   50    25    15
#> 3   Red Male    10   10     7     7
#> 4 Blond Male     3   30     5     8
#> 
#> $Female
#>    Hair    Sex Brown Blue Hazel Green
#> 1 Black Female    36    9     5     2
#> 2 Brown Female    66   34    29    14
#> 3   Red Female    16    7     7     7
#> 4 Blond Female     4   64     5     8
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option is `tapply`

```
tapply(tab[,'count'], tab[1:3], FUN = I)
```

Or we can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tab)[, list(list(dcast(.SD, Hair ~Eye))), Sex]$V1
```

---

Or it may be better to have a 2D data

```
dcast(setDT(tab), Hair + Sex ~Eye)
```